# Trivia Champions logic puzzle on SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new on using swi Prolog, now i'm trying to solve this logic puzzle using Prolog http://www.allstarpuzzles.com/logic/00335.html

But when I tried to run the program, the program seems stop responding and the Prolog freeze. It seems I'm having a problem on determining the score for each team.
Here is my Prolog code :

```
team(dirtydozen).
team(plough).
team(barflyers).
team(threestooges).
team(friends).

pub(maid).
pub(old).
pub(clown).
pub(king).
pub(queen).

score(75).
score(74).
score(73).
score(72).
score(71).
score(70).
score(69).
score(68).
score(67).
score(66).
score(65).
score(64).
score(63).
score(62).
score(61).
score(60).


solve :-
  score(Score1),score(Score2),score(Score3),score(Score4),score(Score5),
  pub(Pub1),pub(Pub2),pub(Pub3),pub(Pub4),pub(Pub5),

  Hasil = [[dirtydozen,Pub1,Score1],
       [plough,Pub2,Score2],
       [barflyers,Pub3,Score3],
       [threestooges,Pub4,Score4],
       [friends,Pub5,Score5]],
 Score1 is Score2 + 6,
 Score1 is Score3 + 9,
 \+ member([threestooges,maid,_],Hasil),

 member([friends,_,A],Hasil),
 member([_,old,B],Hasil),
 member([_,clown,C],Hasil),
 member([_,king,D],Hasil),
 (A-B) is 2*(C-D),
 member([_,queen,E],Hasil),
 member([threestooges,_,F],Hasil),
 F >= E+3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost right. There are only four problems. ;-) 
First, here is an almost working version:

```
team(dirtydozen).
team(plough).
team(barflyers).
team(threestooges).
team(friends).

pub(maid).
pub(old).
pub(clown).
pub(king).
pub(queen).

score(75).
score(74).
score(73).
score(72).
score(71).
score(70).
score(69).
score(68).
score(67).
score(66).
score(65).
score(64).
score(63).
score(62).
score(61).
score(60).

solve(Hasil) :-
    Hasil = [[dirtydozen,Pub1,Score1],
         [plough,Pub2,Score2],
         [barflyers,Pub3,Score3],
         [threestooges,Pub4,Score4],
         [friends,Pub5,Score5]],
    member([friends,_,A],Hasil),
    member([_,old,B],Hasil),
    member([_,clown,C],Hasil),
    member([_,king,D],Hasil),
    member([_,queen,E],Hasil),
    member([threestooges,_,F],Hasil),
    \+ member([threestooges,maid,_],Hasil),
    score(Score2),
    Score1 is Score2 + 6,
    score(Score3),
    Score1 is Score3 + 9,
    score(Score1),
    score(Score4),
    score(Score5),
    AB is A-B,
    AB is 2*(C-D),
    F >= E+3,
    pub(Pub1),
    pub(Pub2),
    pub(Pub3),
    pub(Pub4),
    pub(Pub5).
```

Almost, because it gives solutions, and fast, and they are correct according to your specification. However, there are many and that is because you did not specify that all pubs/teams/scores must be different from each other, so for example

```
[[dirtydozen,old,75],[plough,clown,69],[barflyers,queen,66],
 [threestooges,king,75], [friends,old,63]]
```

is a solution, even though "old" and "75" are in it twice. If you are using SWI, then add `all_different` calls from the clp_fd package or do it manually:

```
A \= B, A \= C, ... B \= C etc.
```

Now, about the freezing: This was just because of suboptimal ordering of your clauses. Just look at the `score`s and `pub`s first. In the first two lines of your `solve` predicate every possible permutation of those two is assigned to the `Score[N]` and `Pub[N]` variables. Try to calculate how many possible assignments there are! Only then your program proceeds by checking if the assignment in question conforms to the rules.

By reordering your conditions I ruled out a lare number of assignments from the beginning. Take these lines for example:

```
score(Score1), score(Score2), Score1 is Score2 + 2,...
```

This could evaluate like this:

```
Score1 = 75, Score2 = 75, 75 is 75+2? 
Score1 = 74, Score2 = 75, 74 is 75+2? 
Score1 = 73, Score2 = 75, 73 is 75+2? 
Score1 = 72, Score2 = 75, 72 is 75+2? 
...
```

All in all, up to 225 combinations of Score1 and Score2 must be checked to see whether they could be the correct assignments.

Now let's consider the reordered version:

```
score(Score2), Score1 is Score2 + 2, score(Score1),...
```

Evaluation now runs along those lines:

```
Score2 = 75, Score1 = 77, score(77)?
Score2 = 74, Score1 = 76, score(76)?
Score2 = 73, Score1 = 75, score(75)?
```

And we are down to only 15 valid assignments. So the rule is: Try to fix these variables to each other in order not to let the tree spread out more than necessary. Fix moving targets!

The only two other minor problems: 1) `(A-B) is 2*(C-D)` does not work, because it states, that the result of evaluating `2*(C-D)` must result not in an integer, but in a term of the form `(A-B)`. Introduce an intermediate variable to resolve. And 2) you did not make `solve` return anything useful, so it said only `true`. Don't know if that's what you wanted. ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation, now it's finally working. :)